# Update a Django QS with annotated data from a postgres JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to update my queryset with some data from a JSONField from that QS.

Action has the ForeignKey `Service` and the postgres JSONField `data`, and I want to move the `service_id` values from the `data` field to the new ForeignKey.

```py
updated_actions = (
    Action.objects.filter(data__service_id__isnull=False)
    .annotate(new_service=KeyTransform('service_id', 'data', output_field=IntegerField()))
    .update(service=F('new_service'))
)
```

If I print out values for `new_service` here they are definitely ints, but I'm getting:

```
Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "service_id" is of type integer but expression is of type jsonb
```

Model:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Action(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(null=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey(
        Service,
        related_name='actions',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Is there any way of getting this to work with `update`?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You probably want to use `KeyTransform('data', 'service_id', output_field=IntegerField())`? Can you share your models?

Comment: With `KeyTransform` you add the key you want first. If I print `updated_actions.values('new_service')` after annotating I get `<ActionQueryset [{'new_service': 192062}, {'new_service': 192061}...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got round this was to use raw SQL:

```py
updated_actions = Action.objects.filter(data__service_id__isnull=False).update(
    service_id=RawSQL('SELECT (data->>service_id)::integer', [])
)
```